# How I can aggregate my matches from find command by grepped values?

Tags: bash, grep, find

I am looking for all occurences of `<source_model>.*</source_model>` at any files located at `./vendor/magento/*/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`:

```
find ./vendor/magento/ -type f -path */etc/adminhtml/system.xml -exec grep -P "<source_model>.*</source_model>" {} +
```

But the output is in a form of:

```
./vendor/magento/module-authorizenet-cardinal/etc/adminhtml/system.xml:                        <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
```

And I want to extract the value:

```
<source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
<source_model>Magento\Captcha\Model\Config\Mode</source_model>
...
```

So I can sort it. How I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior of `grep` when given multiple files to search through is to append the name of the file to each line of output. So you are seeing this output because you are using `-exec ... +` which tries to launch as few instances as possible by lumping the files together, as opposed to `-exec ... \;` which will run the command for each file separately. So, you have a few options (note the quotes around the `-path` value, that's important otherwise the `*` will be expanded by the shell before `find` sees it):

1. Use `-exec \;`

   ```
    find ./vendor/magento/ -type f -path '*/etc/adminhtml/system.xml' \
       -exec grep -P "<source_model>.*</source_model>" {} \;
   ```
2. If you are using GNU `grep`, the default on Linux systems, you can use the `-h` flag to tell it to suppress printing the file names

   ```
    find ./vendor/magento/ -type f -path '*/etc/adminhtml/system.xml' \
       -exec grep -hP "<source_model>.*</source_model>" {} +
   ```

Of course, for all of these, if you are using a `grep` implementation that supports it, you probably also want the `-o` flag so `grep` will only print the matching portion of the line.

Comment: **Note for other ppl:** at approach 1 mentioned above the command *must* end with `;`

Comment: What do you mean, @DimitriosDesyllas? Isn't that exactly what the first paragraph explains and what the first approach is using? The only difference between what I wrote and your original was the `\;` instead of `+`, after all. That and properly quoting which isn't really relevant here. Am I missing something?

Comment: `grep` is not a XML parser... Better use a real parser. What about opening/closing tags on different lines by example?